# How to add more then one files in the cab using makecab

Tags: cab

I want to make make cab file and the cab file should contain more then one files. (eg:- test.dll,ATL80.dll,Microsoft.VC80.ATL.manifest etc).

I tried below command 
makecab Test.dll Test.cab 
it works fine and adds only test.dll in the cab file.
How can we add more then one file in the cab file.
Is there any specific command or process to add more then one file in the cab.
Please note that i  do not want to use cabarc.exe to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: I created ss64.ddf below is the content of SS64.ddf:
.OPTION EXPLICIT
.Set CabinetNameTemplate=TEST.CAB
.Set Cabinet=on
.Set Compress=on
"Test.dll"
"Test.inf"
"ATL80.dll"
"MSVCR80.dll"
"MSVCP80.dll"
"Microsoft.VC80.CRT.manifest"
"Microsoft.VC80.ATL.manifest"
And i am trying command 
makecab /F SS64.ddf but it is saying file SS^$.ddf is not found. I cross verified the path it is correct.

Comment: FWIW, your ddf file is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using makecab and a .ddf file
 1. Create a ddf file with your files in it (make.ddf):
    ;*** Sample Source Code MakeCAB Directive file example
    ;
    .OPTION EXPLICIT     ; Generate errors 
    .Set CabinetNameTemplate=ThyName.cab
    .Set Cabinet=on
    .Set Compress=on

```
"test.dll"
"ATL80.dll"
"Microsoft.VC80.ATL.manifest"
;*** <the end>
```

2. run the makecab:
   makecab.exe /F make.ddf